# Socket cannot connect to server via mobile internet because I use hostname instead of IP but works in i.e. Eclipse and via WIFI

Tags: java, android, sockets, mobile, hostname

I have problem with connection between Android phone and server on Raspberry Pi via mobile internet. I created simple server on RPi and Client on android. I also instaled Weaved software to DNS problem. When I use simple client in another PC in i.e Eclipse I can connect to server using i.e:

```
client = new Socket("proxy.11.xxx.net", 54812)
```

The same is on android when I use WIFI. Problem starts when I switch off WIFI. Socket dosn't connect to server. I set permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

There is no any exceptions. Socket created successful but doesn't connect to server.

I.E I put

```
proxy.11.xxx.net:54812
```

to web browser and enter, there is connection to server.
Ofcourse it works when I am in local network via WIFI and put straight IP number of RPi but it isn't what I mean. I want to be able connect via Internet from android. Why I can connect the same address from PC and on android not?

Anyone can help/give advice?

**EDIT:**

When I use: `new Socket (proxy.11.xxx.net,54812)` there is no Exception. Socket is created ok: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tg1R.jpg

When I use `new Socket(http://proxy.11.xxx.net,54812)`:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "http://proxy11.yoics.net": No address associated with hostname
06-10 22:03:46.576 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:457)
06-10 22:03:46.576 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
06-10 22:03:46.576 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
06-10 22:03:46.576 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:109)
06-10 22:03:46.576 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
06-10 22:03:46.576 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
06-10 22:03:46.576 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight.Client.openSocket(Client.java:50)
06-10 22:03:46.576 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight.Client.doInBackground(Client.java:76)
06-10 22:03:46.576 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight.Client.doInBackground(Client.java:30)
06-10 22:03:46.576 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
06-10 22:03:46.576 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-10 22:03:46.576 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-10 22:03:46.576 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-10 22:03:46.576 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-10 22:03:46.576 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-10 22:03:46.577 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
06-10 22:03:46.577 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
06-10 22:03:46.577 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
06-10 22:03:46.577 29922-29944/com.mmc.mateusz.rpilight W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
```

Comment: What is the actual error that the socket reports when it cannot connect?

Comment: This sounds like a networking issue, not a programming issue.  Try asking on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a networking issue, not a coding issue.

In order to access the RPi over the Internet, you need a *public* Internet IP address that can route traffic to the RPi.  And if you want clients to connect using a static hostname instead of the IP directly, you need a DNS registration (in this case, provided by `weaved.com`) that maps the desired hostname to the current IP address.

For the IP address itself, the RPi needs either:

1. its own *direct* connection to the Internet, so it has a public IP address assigned by your ISP.
2. to be connected to a LAN that has a public Internet IP address.  The LAN router(s) must have port forwarding configured to forward outside traffic to the RPi.  Clients will be connecting to the router that is directly connected to the Internet, and then the router(s) will forward the connections to the RPi.

Either way, your ISP must also not be blocking inbound client connections.  Some ISPs block customers from hosting their own servers, or they charge extra for that feature.  Check with your ISP.

These issues are not a factor when your client app(s) and RPi are on the same side of your LAN, such as when both are connected to the same router via WiFi.

So, in short, make sure you have a public IP address that provides a viable route to exchange data packets between the RPi and outside Internet clients, and make sure you have a static hostname that can be resolved to that IP address.

Comment: I have "GENERIC TCP" in weaved.com. I can connect via `proxy11.yoics.net` name host from PC using client written in Eclipse. I do the same thing in android but there is a problem. Why on PC in Java something is working ok, but the same code(almost, but this part is the same) doesn't?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the client is running on a PC or an Android device. What matters is the network setup. If your PC can connect, but the Android device cannot, then your PC must be taking a different networking route to reach the RPi, not the public Internet. I just tried connecting to `proxy11.yoics.net:54812` from my machine, and it is not able to connect (I can ping the IP, though). So you clearly don't have your network routing configured correctly to allow a client to connect to your RPi over the public Internet. Which means this issue should be on ServerFault instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: So is there no option to connect to RPi via mobile internet from android except port forwarding?  So why is there this service in weaved. com?

Comment: hehehe this host name is imagine you cannot connect to this because  I change hostname.  But if you want I can write truly host name

Comment: This is not an Android issue, it is a networking issue. If your RPi is running behind a router, you need to enable port forwarding on the router so *ANY* outside client can connect to a designated IP/port and be forwarded to your RPi's IP/port. `weaved.com` merely provides a way for clients to resolve your hostname to your public IP address, nothing more. If the IP belongs to the router, it needs to provide further routing (ie port forwarding) to the RPi. That has nothing to do with `weaved.com`.  Oh yeah, and also make sure there are no firewalls blocking inbound connections, either.

Comment: Okey.  so If I want create server for my app where can I do this.  is there any free hosting providing things?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with hosting your own server, such as on your RPi, *IF* your ISP allows inbound connections, and *IF* your Internet router (if any) allows it, and *IF* firewall(s) (if any) allow it. This is basic networking. On the other hand, if you plan on releasing your Android app publically/commercially, you might consider creating a server on an Internet hosting service (there are many hosting services to choose from, but it really depends on what your server really needs to do and how you want to develop for it), or create your own server with a dedicated Internet connection.

Comment: You were right. I did experiment. I connected PC to internet form phone then I tried to connect from Eclipse and the same as in Android - no connection no exceptions. Thanks again.